# Is an aqueous solution of lithium superoxide basic or neutral?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, acid-base

Is the aqueous solution of lithium superoxide basic or neutral?

I know that $\ce{Li}$ is a metal, thus its oxide ($\ce{Li2O}$) produces base in reaction with water.

Comment: pKa of $\ce{HOO^.}$ is 4.88.

Comment: It is hard to imagine lithium superoxide itself.

Comment: @NilayGhosh https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lithium_superoxide // The better question would be "Is solution formed by dissolution of LiO2 in water basic or neutral?"

Comment: This assumes we can get the lithium superoxide into water at all. It seems to be stable only at very low temperatures or in nonpolar solvents.

Comment: @OscarLanzi Like that.

Answer (score 3):

Lithium superoxide is only stable in a dry atmosphere and at temperatures below $\pu{70 K}$ $(\pu{-203 °C})$ according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lithium_superoxide). So it cannot be dissolved in water. And in the presence of water, it gets decomposed into $\ce{LiOH}$ and $\ce{O2}.$